# Can I keep a forked github repo up to date from original?

Tags: github

If I fork a repo so I can add my own changes, am I essentially cutting myself off from any new modifications or changes to the original repo, or can I update my forked version with the new changes and whilst keeping mine?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your fork in sync and keep your changes in another branch, check the docks from GitHub about [Syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/), basically you need to [configure a remote to fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/):

```
 $ git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
 $ git fetch upstream
 $ git checkout master
 $ git merge upstream/master
```

To force your local `master` branch to be like the `upstream/master`:

```
 $ git checkout master
 $ git reset --hard upstream/master
```

To keep your remote updated:

```
 $ git push origin master --force
```